# Passing model object and List to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

Im fairly new to ASP.NET MVC, so please bear with me. Im trying to pass a model object and a List to my viewmodel.

This is my code:

```
ViewModel:
    public class SchemaModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA> Schema { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA> Ar { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA> Veckor { get; set; }

    }


Controller:
 public ActionResult Schema(int schemaID)
        {
            using (var db = new TTSPEntities())
            {
                var veckor = (from AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA in db.AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA
                              where AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.AS_AH_LNR == (schemaID)
                              select new
                              {
                                  AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.AS_SC_VECKA
                              }).ToString().Distinct().ToList();

                var model = new SchemaModel
                {
                    Schema = db.AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.Where(A => A.AS_AH_LNR == schemaID).ToList(),
                };
                return View(model, veckor);
            }
        }
```

Im getting the following error:
Argument 2: Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.list' to 'string'.

I have been trying to aproach this on a few other ways, but can't seem to get it right. I guess there is something wrong with my datatypes and casts.

Anyone got any ideas?

Edit:
If i do it like this, which makes alot more sense to me i still get an error.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Schema(int schemaID)
        {
            using (var db = new TTSPEntities())
            {

                ////Hämtar veckor och sparar varje unikt veckonummer i en lista.
                var veckor = (from AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA in db.AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA
                              where AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.AS_AH_LNR == (schemaID)
                              select new
                              {
                                  AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.AS_SC_VECKA
                              }).Distinct().ToList();

                var model = new SchemaModel
                {
                    Schema = db.AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.Where(A => A.AS_AH_LNR == schemaID).ToList(),
                    Veckor = veckor
                };
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

I get the following Error:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Is it because you're returning a string `return `View(model, vecktor)` and the @Model declaration in your view is of type `List`?

Comment: Remove `.ToString()` in your query. But your `return View(model, veckor);` makes no sense anyway. The 1st parameter is the name of thew view and the 2nd is the model to be passed to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I still get the same error without `.ToString()`. Yeah, that sure is true. Can't seem to get it to work. Please look at my edit in the mainpost.

Comment: You need to put the full detail of the error - what type to what? And `Vector` is `IEnumerable<AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA>` but your query is selecting `AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.AS_SC_VECKA`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Updated error message in main post.

Comment: Its more that that - its _List<something> to IEnumerable<somethingElse>_ - they are not the same types (see my previous comment). And stop using `var`!

Comment: Okey. AS_SC_VECKA is a int field in my database.

So if i change to `public IEnumerable<int> AS_SC_VECKA { get; set; }` in my ViewModel, and instead of var i use `IEnumerable<int> veckor =` i get the following error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int? AS_SC_VECKA>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Because `select new { ... }` creates an anonymous object. Just use `select AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.AS_SC_VECKA` if you just want `IEnumerable<int>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it like this solved my problem:

```
Controller:                 
                var model = new SchemaModel
                {
                    Schema = db.AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.Where(A => A.AS_AH_LNR == schemaID).ToList(),
                    AS_SC_VECKA = (from AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA in db.AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA
                                   where AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.AS_AH_LNR == (schemaID)
                                   select AS_AVTAL_SCHEMA.AS_SC_VECKA
                              ).Distinct().ToList()
            };

Viewmodel:
    public class SchemaModel
    {
        public List<int?> AS_SC_VECKA { get; set; }
    }
```